# Flexbox centre aligning does not work as expected

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to center align a triangle at the bottom of a div using flex box. The method i have previously used is not working as expected. I'm also using Tailwindcss but you can still see the CSS code below.

```
 <div class="flex-col items-center mb-20 h-64">
        <div class="bg-yellow-300 w-full h-56">
         </div>
        <div class="arrow-down">
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items-center {
    align-items: center;
    
}

.bg-yellow-300 {
   background-color: #808080;
 
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
  }

.h-56 {
    height: 14rem;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/chrisrobbouk/pen/qBZOZwx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the triangle, add the rule `margin: 0 auto 0 auto` for the `arrow-down` class.

```css
.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.items-center {
    align-items: center;
    
}

.bg-yellow-300 {
   background-color: #808080;
 
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid #f00;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  }

.h-56 {
    height: 14rem;
```

```html
 <div class="flex-col items-center mb-20 h-64">
        <div class="bg-yellow-300 w-full h-56">
         </div>
        <div class="arrow-down">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey! That worked perfectly

Comment: If my answer helped you, please check the box to the left of my answer. Happy to help :)

Comment: I forgot to tell you... you have a `flex-col` class, and in css you specified it without a dot. You have `flex-col` like this, but you need `.flex-col` like this.

Comment: good spot! thanks again